# What is Wrong in this Simple Java Game Loop?

Tags: java, loops

I've tried to figure this out or find another way around for about 3 Days now, but I can't make it work...
Basic I'm converting an Game Applet to an Application, but I can't get the Game Loop Working. Plus in NetBeans, I made a Window, but it doesn't show up even if I Set it Visible. If you got a tutorial on how to make a Simple Game loop, it would be great. I'm desperate, Please Help Me!

Here's the code of my main Class

```
package MainClass;

import javax.swing.*;

 public class MainClass implements Runnable{

    Painter panel = new Painter();
    JavaPowderToy Screen = new JavaPowderToy();
    Thread t = new Thread();

    public void run()
    {

    Initialize();

    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            panel.Paint();
            Thread.sleep(15);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    }

void MainClass()
{
  t.start();  

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainClass Java = new MainClass();



}

private void Initialize()
{
    panel.InitializePainting();
    new Window().setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Here's my Painter Class:

```
    package thejavapowdertoy;

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;


    public class Painter extends JPanel implements KeyListener{



    BufferedImage buffer;

   public Painter()
    {
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

   public void InitializePainting()
   {

   }

   public void Paint()
   {
       Graphics2D b = buffer.createGraphics();
       Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)this.getGraphics();
       b.setColor(Color.red);
       b.fillRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
       b.dispose();
       g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, this);
       Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
       g.dispose();
   }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }


    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you define 'doesn't work'? What's it doing that you didn't expect it to? What should it do?

Comment: I think you better go back to the basics - [Learning the Java Language](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MainClass` implements `Runnable` thus I assume you want it to be run by the thread. The thread `t`, however, doesn't know that.

You need to pass the `MainClass` instance to the thread's constructor: `new Thread(this);`

Additionally, your `Painter` panel is not connected to the window you create and thus it would not be visible. Try creating a `JFrame` or `JWindow` and place the painter in it.

Comment: Thanks, the this Was what I needed ( And I was Following a Tutorial, which didn't wrote the "this", weird )

Answer (score 0):

```
void MainClass()
{
  t.start();  

}
```

This is not a constructor, but a method! This is because the thread is not started. Remove the `void`

And also look at the other answers. Basically you have two threads. One the `MainClass` itself and then `t` inside the `MainClass`.